# Background changing not working on Windows Phone 8

Tags: background, windows-phone

I want to change the background image on Windows Phone 8 app. The following code does not work:

```
<phone:Panorama.Background>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="/PanoramaAppTest;component/Assets/background.png"/>
</phone:Panorama.Background>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try your image source. Like this;

```
<phone:Panorama.Background>
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/background.png"/>
```

or

```
<phone:Panorama.Background>
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Assets/background.png"/>     
</phone:Panorama.Background>
```

Actually I don't know but your problem's is location name.